# Minimum number of path distance measurements

Tags: graph-theory

Consider a weighted Graph with edge set E and vertices V.

The aim is to find the weights of all the edges. You have access to distances of paths.

For example, distance of a path ABCD is sum of edge weights of AB, BC, CD.

What is the strategy of choosing minimum number of paths, so that by knowing these distances, all the edge weights can be computed.

Comment: How are you defining the weight of an edge?

Comment: Like in a standard weighted graph. Each edge has a numerical value associated with it called the weight. "Path distance" is sum of all the weights of edges in the path

Comment: Yes, but you mention that you're trying to find the weights. So I assume there's some missing calculation to determine that.

Comment: All the edge weights are unknown. But you can measure path distances. For example you can measure distances of paths ABCD, BCAD, CALK, etc. So, with each of these measurements, you get a linear equation which is sum of some of the weights of edges. With enough equations like these, you can solve them to get all individual weights. The idea is to find the smallest set of paths, which together give all the weights.

Comment: OK, so you have some function that, given a path, will return the total path distance. And you're not allowed to just sample path distances with one edge?

Comment: You are free to do that too. You can sample each edge to get its weight, but that would mean too many measurements. I need to find the "optimal" way of doing this, with "optimal" meaning smallest number of measurements.

Answer (score 0):

For a graph with N edges, you need at least N measurements. Therefore, the simplest way to get all weights is to measure each edge separately.

**Proof**:
Each measurement can be seen as a linear equation where edge weights are variables. Together, the measurements make a system of linear equations. If you have less equations (measurements) than variables (lengths), you get an [undetermined system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underdetermined_system) which has an infinite number of solutions.